# How to write this Dirac delta function in spherical coordinate?

Tags: dirac-delta

I have Dirac delta function in an integral as follows
$$
\delta(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)\; \tag{1}
$$
Is right to write it as follows?
$$
\delta(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)=\frac{1}{r_1^2}\delta(r_1 -r_2)\delta(\cos\theta_1 -\cos\theta_2)\delta(\phi_1 -\phi_2) \tag{2}
$$
Unfortunately I couldn't find Dirac delta in spherical coordinate in books such as Arfken's one so I'm not sure about 2. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We want to determine the distribution $u$ such that for every $f\in C^\infty$ we have
$$
\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{r=0}^\infty u(r,\theta,\phi) \, f(r,\theta,\phi) \, r^2 \sin\theta \, dr \,d\theta \, d\phi
= f(r_0, \theta_0, \phi_0).
$$

It's clear that we can take
$$
u(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{r^2 \sin\theta} \delta(r-r_0) \delta(\theta-\theta_0) \delta(\phi-\phi_0).
$$

Now the composition of $\delta$ with a function $g$ can be written as a sum over the zeros of $g$:
$$
\delta(g(x)) = \sum_{g(x_k)=0} \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|g'(x_k)|},
$$
Taking $g(\theta)=\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0$ we get, for $\theta,\theta_0\in(0,\pi)$ that
$$
\delta(\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0) 
= \frac{\delta(\theta-\theta_0)}{\sin\theta_0}
= \frac{\delta(\theta-\theta_0)}{\sin\theta}
,
$$
we can also write
$$
u(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{r^2} \delta(r-r_0) \delta(\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0) \delta(\phi-\phi_0).
$$